# Largo de un arreglo y puntero en c

Tags: c

```
char *nombre_carrera[] = {"perro prueba0", "perro prueba1", "perro prueba2",...........};
```

¿Cómo puedo saber el largo del arreglo para saber cuántos `perro prueba` hay?

Utilicé `strlen(*nombre_carrera)` pero me da el largo de `"perro prueba0"` solamente y si le pongo `strlen(**nombre_carrera)` o `strlen(nombre_carrera)`  da error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

si quieres saber cuantos elementos tiene el array tienes que utilizar el sizeof en C, El operador sizeof proporciona la cantidad de almacenamiento, en bytes, necesaria para almacenar un objeto del tipo del operando. Este operador permite no tener que especificar tamaños de datos dependientes del equipo en los programas.

```
 #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
    char *nombre_carrera[] = {"perro prueba1", "perro prueba10", "perro prueba200", "Perro"};
    int resul = sizeof(nombre_carrera)/sizeof(char*);
    printf("Tiene: %i", resul);
    }
```